# OnTriggerEnter2D bool alternating true/false after activating

Tags: unity-game-engine

After player enters trigger, bool is not staying true, it is constantly switching between true and false, why does this happen?

```
public bool activated;

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    Debug.Log(activated);
}

void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        activated = true;
    }
}
```

[Console screenshot in Unity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvFmH.png)

Comment: The script is probably attached to other gameObjects also

Comment: I feel so stupid, you are correct, thanks!